# Hystrix Dashboard not coming when freemarker template suffix is added

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker, hystrix, spring-boot-actuator

I have add the hytrix libraries onto my spring boot, spring cloud microservice application. But the problem is that the hystrix dashboard is showing 404 when I hit **http://localhost:8080/omnesys/hystrix**. I debugged and found the issue. The hystrix dashboard was not coming and showing 404 because in my project we have a property in yaml like as shown below

```
spring:
    freemarker:
      suffix: .html
```

The above config is used for one freemarker email feature. If I remove the above property in yaml, hytrix dashboard is coming fine.

Can anyone please help me on this issue.